# What's the equivalent to Marshal.ReadIntPtr(IntPtr) (C#) in Java?

Tags: c#, java, pointers, marshalling

What's the equivalent to `Marshal.ReadIntPtr(IntPtr)` (C#) in Java?

Comment: There is no Marshal.IntPtr method... are you refering to ReadIntPtr or WriteIntPtr?

Comment: very sorry, I mean Marshal.ReadIntPtr(IntPtr) method

Comment: why do you need this in Java?

Comment: I have to translate some code from c# to java. This snippet i can translate: <code>string a = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi((IntPtr) ptr);</code>. But this - doesn`t: <code>string a = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(Marshal.ReadIntPtr((IntPtr) ptr));</code>

Comment: And where exactly do you get unmanaged memory from in Java? That's like asking how to dereference a pointer in java - doesn't make any sense. Obviously you could use a nio buffer, but then that already does have the usual readXXX methods (and then I don't think there's any easy way in Java to find out about native pointer sizes (and what about if the VM is using compressed Oops?)

Comment: In the second code snippet I get IntPtr form dll library. In java i get Pointer via jna.

Comment: And why not return a usable java object (ie in this case probably an int array) from JNI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the following class

```
sun.misc.Unsafe
```

Methods of interest in that class are:

```
public native long getAddress(long address);
public native void putAddress(long address, long value);
public native long allocateMemory(long size);
public native long reallocateMemory(long l, long l1);
public native void setMemory(long l, long l1, byte b);
public native void copyMemory(long l, long l1, long l2);
```

here's an example of its use:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import sun.misc.Unsafe; 
public class Direct {

        public static void main(String... args) {
            Unsafe unsafe = null;

            try {
                Field field = sun.misc.Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
                field.setAccessible(true);
                unsafe = (sun.misc.Unsafe) field.get(null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new AssertionError(e);
            }

            long value = 12345;
            byte size = 1;
            long allocateMemory = unsafe.allocateMemory(size);
            unsafe.putAddress(allocateMemory, value);
            long readValue = unsafe.getAddress(allocateMemory);
            System.out.println("read value : " + readValue);
        }
    }
```

Comment: if we have a structure (c++): struct Test
{
char string1; // "test" // 4 bytes
int value1; // 23 // 4 bytes
char * label; // *label == "str" // 4 bytes
}; If pointer to this structure is "p" (com.sun.jna.Pointer), then the equivalent to Marshal.ReadIntPtr(IntPtr) is p.getPointer(8)